# Drupal redirects to site.local/install.php

Tags: users, installation, configuration

I was working on my branch this morning tweaking some CSS when all of a sudden my Drupal site went into a dead mode. I am running multi site mode and the local.settings.php in the individual sites is being ignored on load.

The parent settings.php file is also being ignored on load.

The site redirects to the installation url: http://site.local/install.php

What could have possibly went wrong and how do I go about resolving that?

Comment: Does "your branch" mean you're using git?  have you checked that the settings files are in your branch? Also, check that your database server is running, and try deliberately breaking the settings files to see if they're being ignored. Finally, check that your sites/sites.php is on your branch and correct

Comment: Hi, 

My local settings configurations are upto date. I have checked out my branch. Settings file are indeed within my working branch. The sites/sites.php exists and has remained unchanged since the day it was created. 

If you need anything else, please let me know. Correct settings in the local.settings.php

Comment: OK, but now it redirects to the install script,right? Which means it doesn't find the database. Does it return a 500 error if you deliberately break the settings file?

Comment: No. The sites folder was renamed and it did not match the sites folder specified in the stes.php folder. :-(

Thank you very much. I had to read through you comment again to come right. I owe you a beer.